# Styling options in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter, styling

Is there any options available in Python tkinter that can be used to build a modern-day GUI. For instance, we can change the style of a button, etc. In short, I want to change the whole look & feel of the GUI.

Regards.

Comment: Are you aware of `ttk`?

Comment: Having elementary knowledge of that...Could you please elaborate what sort of options are available for styling in ttk ?

Comment: CustomTkinter: https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com